# "Smart" page breaking for boxed content

Tags: page-breaking, boxes, minipage

I am trying to load content from a central .tex file, then display it.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% central.tex %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\saveContent{A}{this is content "A"}
\saveContent{B}{this is content "B"}
\saveContent{C}{this is content "C"}
\saveContent{D}{this is content "D"}
% \vdots
```

.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% document.tex %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\input{central.tex}

\useContent{A}
\useContent{B}
\useContent{C}

\begin{document}
  \displayUsableContent
\end{document}
```

*The particular use case is that this allows me to write problem sets and exams using a question bank, editing only the top few lines of the document. I am sure there are many ways to do this.*

Different content blocks have different sizes. Let's say that `A` takes up 0.5 (vertical) pages, `B` takes up 1.0 page, `C` takes up 1.5 pages, and `D` takes up 0.5 pages. I would like them to display as

```
+---+  +---+  +---+  +---+
| A |  | B |  | C |  | C |
|   |  | B |  | C |  | D | % (breaking D onto its own page would be acceptable)
|(1)|  |(2)|  |(3)|  |(4)|
+---+  +---+  +---+  +---+
```

I have tried wrapping the content in `minipage`, which cuts off the last 0.5 pages of `C`:

```
+---+  +---+  +---+  +---+
| A |  | B |  | C |  | D |
|   |  | B |  | C |  |   | % where is my C :(
|(1)|  |(2)|  |(3)|  |(4)|
+---+  +---+  +---+  +---+
```

I have tried wrapping the content in `list`, which doesn't respect trying to keep content together where possible:

```
+---+  +---+  +---+  +---+
| A |  | B |  | C |  | D |
| B |  | C |  | C |  |   | % B is broken but doesn't need to be :(
|(1)|  |(2)|  |(3)|  |(4)|
+---+  +---+  +---+  +---+
```

Is there a way to have LaTeX automatically break pages in this way? The rough rule is, *If additional content cannot fit on the same page as previous content, put it on a new page; create page breaks in content if necessary*.

Comment: Nice pages! If I understand correctly, you would want `|A|BB|CC|C|D|` effectively having 5 pages in the end? Or is your first design example acceptable?

Comment: @thymaro either 4 or 5 pages would work. 5 pages could probably be done with \clearpage, but I'd rather condense content where possible.

Comment: What is the "boxed" in your title? Is it because you tried minipages? I don't see any other reference to boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about how to apply this solution but I think it can work. It consists in using `tcolorboxes` to include the problems in main document. In this case it's possible to control how much vertical space is used by a box. By default it's its natural height but you can use options like `feight fill` to use all available space in every page. It's also possible to use option `heigth fixed for` option in `breakable` boxes to decide if last fragment uses a complete page or only its natural height. Here you have some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{enhanced, breakable, height fixed for=all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill, title=Problem A]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill, title=Problem B]
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Problem C]
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[height fixed for=none, title=Problem D]
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[height fill, title=Problem E]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: option `blanker` will suppress all frames and colors but keep vertical space.

Comment: +1: How can this be the first upvote? :)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the content is free to undergo page breaks (not boxed), just put

```
\filbreak
```

between content items